# Rank is None inside the mapped function when running huggingface Dataset.map() on multiple GPUs with with_rank=True?

Tags: python, huggingface-datasets

I am trying to run Dataset.map() function on a huggingface Dataset on multiple GPUs. As instructed [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/process#map) my code looks like this:

```
def translate(example, rank, model):
    os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = str(rank % torch.cuda.device_count())
    example['premise'] = model.translate(example['premise'])
    return example

ds_map = ds.map(translate, with_rank=True, fn_kwargs= {'model':model})
```

I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'

which means the `rank` argument inside `translate` function is None. But I do not understand why that would be so.

I am not very familiar with working on multiple GPUs so any help to understand the issue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Faced similar issue. resolved by adding `num_proc` parameter in map

```
ds_map = ds.map(translate, with_rank=True,num_proc=2, fn_kwargs= {'model':model})
```